# Adding multiple character counters by a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I wrote the following function using jQuery to calculate and update remaining character count in an element.

```
function setRemainingChars(containerID, targetID, maxCount){
    $con = $('#'+containerID), $target =  $('#'+targetID);
    $con.css('resize','none');
    $target.html = (maxCount+' remaining');
    $con.keyup(function() {
        var texlen = $con.val().length;
        var rem = maxCount-texlen;
        $target.html(rem+' remaining');
    });
}
```

And I would call this function as `setRemainingChars('mytextid','myspanid',100)` where the html will be as follows:

```
<textarea id='mytextid'></textarea>
<span id='myspanid'></span>
```

This works fine when there is only one of these in the page. But when this function is called multiple times, it only works for the last one.

Why and how can I solve it?

Comment: If you have multiple components with the same id on the page, think about using classes instead

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We don't know why without seeng sample html and seeing how you implement this

Comment: @christopher-moore I added different ids for the different elements

Comment: @charlietfl I updated the question by adding a sample scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem stems from not using `var` or `let` to declare local variables. This is a terrible practice, as witnessed by your problem, and can be difficult to debug

Without it they become globals and each time you call the function you overwrite those globals instead of having local instances

Change

```
$con = $('#'+containerID), $target =  $('#'+targetID);
```

To

```
var $con = $('#'+containerID), $target =  $('#'+targetID);
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/1hnhkk1k/)**</kbd>

Comment: Yes it was my major mistake. Thanks!